# Un-escaping characters present in recordset that is bound to control in Access 2003

Tags: ms-access, recordset, escaping

I have some data stored in SQL Server that contains apostrophes. Within the SQL Server table to apostrophe is escaped. For example the phrase "Roberts's thesis" is stored as "Robert''s Thesis". I use Access 2003 as a font end for the application and I use ADO to access the data stored in SQL Server using Stored Procedures.

The issue I am having is how to "un-escape" the double apostrophe when the data is retrieved using a recordset and then bound to a control. Here is some sample code.

```
  Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
  Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset


  Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
  cnn.ConnectionString = myConnectionString
  cnn.Open

  Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
  Set rs.ActiveConnection = cnn
  rs.Source = "EXEC uspMyStoredProcedureName"

  rs.LockType = adLockOptimistic
  rs.CursorType = adOpenStatic
  rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
  rs.Open

  Set ListControl.Recordset = rs

  Set rs = Nothing
  Set cnn = Nothing
```

Do I have to "loop" through the recordset manually and un-escape the apostrophe? Thank you.

Comment: It looks as though I don't need to be storing the data "escaped" in the database at all. I guess I am so used to inserting data via direct SQL and having to escape certain characters. Thanks to "bobince" and "Frank"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to unescape anything. The doubled-apostrophe form is only used for string literals inside SQL statements. The actual value inserted in the database by `INSERT... 'Robert''s Thesis';` is `Robert's Thesis`, and that is the value you'll get out when you read it from a recordset grabbed from a `SELECT`.

If whatever's inside `uspMyStoredProcedureName` is doing something weird to cause doubled apostrophes to get returned then it's broken and needs fixing; if you have `Robert''s Thesis` as an actual value in the database, then you've inserted broken data and you should be looking at fixing the code that's done that, and cleaning up the data.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no possibility to change uspMyStoredProcedureName, then You will have to loop through the resultset.
Otherwise, changing the select statement in the stored procedure from `col` to `Replace(col, '''''', '''')` would do the trick.
Yes, there are six single quotes in the second argument and four in the third: Two enclose a string, and within that, each quote is doubled to escape it.

BTW: Why are the data stored with doubled quotes at all?